# More black links on deleted question page

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, deleted-questions, design

This is a continuation of this question:  [Black links on new duplicate banner are counter intuitive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166507/black-links-on-new-duplicate-banner-are-counter-intuitive).

On [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), when users with less than 10k view a deleted question they land at a page that looks (something) like this:

[image]

As you can see, the links are black.  Can we change this please?

**EDIT**

I've just noticed you only see this on pages where the OP deleted it, not on ones deleted my moderators.

Example post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/235879/how-to-install-ubuntu-wubi#comment293222_235879

Comment: Ask Ubuntu's styling is quite "different" and it may make sense first discussing things here (or in Ask Ubuntu's chat room). Although in this specific case, it would be quite difficult for <10K users to find deleted stuff to analyze.

Comment: Also, could you or anyone else please post a couple of links to deleted stuff so I can see what they look like?

Comment: @vasa1 I'll see if I can find one.

Comment: @vasa1 Edited one in.

Comment: I think what you're seeing is the dominance of "aesthetics" over functionality. I feel there's not much point in pointing out such things. I just have my own style sheet with blue for unvisited and red for visited links.

Comment: @vasa1  I don't understand why you think this shouldn't be changed.  1. It makes the page look ugly.  2.  People can, and do, totally miss the links. 3. It's totally against the way the rest of the site is. We can't all be expected to use custom CSS to get the site to look the way is should.

Comment: Calm down ;) I'm just saying that you're going to keep running into this issue in a lot of places. Ultimately, you'll reach a point of "to heck with it" and "I'll just look out for myself" which is where I'm at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site has had several design updates and this is now fixed.